# Get custom property of signed in user in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm working on a .NET Core project and I have added a custom column to the 
**ASPNetUsers** table called `DisplayName` that users set during the registration. I've successfully migrated the tables with that data and everything works fine.

However in my Login partial, I have to access the user's data through 
**UserManager**, and there's no method of getting that `DisplayName` INSTEAD of the `Username`.

What do I need to do to extend the function of the "normal" Identity manager to get the custom method to retrieve the text that's stored in `DisplayName` column?

Answer (score 1):

By getting the current user I can then access the `DisplayName` property as a normal property of an object.

```
var currentUser = await _UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);
var displayName = currentUser.DisplayName;
```